# Denoting large recurring parts of an equation by a variable

Tags: replacement, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have formula like the following:

```
(1 - x) (1 - y) + ((1 - x) (1 - y))/(z + 2)
```

Obviously,  (1 - x) (1 - y) is found a couple of places in the formula.

How do I denote  (1 - x) (1 - y) by z and thereby simplify my formula?

Comment: `PolynomialReduce` is a good function for computations of this type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking for an automated process you may find `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression `` useful:

```
$Context = "Compile`"; (* improve formatting for copy *)

Experimental`OptimizeExpression[(1 - x) (1 - y) + ((1 - x) (1 - y))/(z + 2)]
```

> ```
> Experimental`OptimizedExpression[
>  Block[{$1, $2, $3, $4},
>     $1 = -x; $2 = 1 + $1; $3 = -y; $4 = 1 + $3; $2 $4 + ($2 $4)/(2 + z)
>  ]
> ]
> ```

Or perhaps a simple replacement can suit your needs:

```
(1 - x) (1 - y) + ((1 - x) (1 - y))/(z + 2) /. ((1 - x) (1 - y)) :> zz
```

> ```
> zz + zz/(2 + z)
> ```

I used `zz` instead of `z` for clarity.

Answer (score 7):

```
Simplify[(1 - x) (1 - y) + ((1 - x) (1 - y))/(z + 2), z == (1 - x) (1 - y)]
```

> $$\frac{z (z+3)}{z+2}$$